# 5001 and 5008 Errors While Importing a Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've a class file named `PlayerClass.as` which is in the same directory with my `.fla` file.

`PlayerClass.as` starts with:`package PlayerClass {`

`.fla` file starts with: `import PlayerClass;`

My function is: `PlayerClass.SimplePlayer(Sound1);`

But I'm getting `errors 5001 and 5008`. How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what Rachel said.

In your case, the PlayerClass should have a empty package

```
package {
//... your class definition here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ActionScript Error #5001: The name of package does not reflect the location of this file

ActionScript Error #5008: Means you're trying to use a class but the class is in a subdirectory that should be reflected in the package name. An example:-

```
c:\PackageTest\com\ayumilove\Game.as

package com.ayumilove
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Game extends MovieClip
    {

        public function Game() 
        {
            trace("Game Created");
        }

     }

}

//An example to instantiate the class
import com.ayumilove.Game;
var game:Game = new Game();
```

Hope this helps. Just check your directories and make sure they are all spelled correctly.